# Is it possible to send ESC/POS commands to EPSON TM-T88IV Printer through Windows command line?

Tags: electrical-engineering, computer-engineering, computer-hardware, computer

I am interested in learning more about ESC/POS commands. I have an EPSON TM-T88IV printer connected to my PC via parallel cable at port LPT1. Connected to this printer is an APG Cash Drawer. The PC is running Windows 7 Professional. I would like to know if it is possible to send ESC/POS commands to this printer through the Windows command line. If not, I would like to know what steps to take to be able to set up some sort of test environment.

Answer (score 1):

In principle this should work fine. According to https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=82 the commands to drive the printer are just combinations of ASCII control characters like ESC, FS, GS, etc, which can be transmitted to the printer exactly the same way as "ordinary" printable letters and numbers. A complete table of ASCII codes is here: http://www.asciitable.com/

How you actually send an "unprintable" character like ESC etc will depend on the software you are using. You may be able to simply "type" the characters - for example to generate ESC (character number 27 in the ASCII table) hold down the ALT key while typing 027 on the numeric keypad, use ALT + 029 for GS, etc.

Comment: open command prompt, type `COPY CON: LPT1:` and type your codes away. IIRC, `Ctrl+Z` on a line alone ends the input.